# How should I show this apparently really old date in Crystal Reports?

Tags: date, crystal-reports, formatting, crystal-reports-xi

I have a string field where dates are sometimes entered as YYYY-MM-DD, and am displaying it on a Crystal Report as a date.  I was using

```
DateValue ({Table.Field})
```

to show the date, then formatting the dates as MM/DD/YYYY.  That looked good until I saw a date of 10/12/1931 and saw that it didn't match what was in the database: "0010-12-31".

I know that is just a typo, and I can see that the date probably should be 12/31/2010, but I want to display what they entered.  So, just for this time, I put in the following:

```
if {Table.Field} = '0010-12-31' then
  Date(0010, 12, 31)
else
  DateValue ({Table.Field})
```

When I do that, it displays 12/31/10, even though I've requested a 4 digit year.  I guess I'm good with that, since it's not as deceptive.

But, what should Crystal do with what appears to be really old dates?

And, more importantly, is this now going to choke if dates are entered in a different format?  I think it will.

```
if NOT (IsNull({Table.Field})) then
  Date(ToNumber (Left ({Table.Field}, 4)),
       ToNumber (Mid ({Table.Field}, 6, 2)),
       ToNumber (Right ({Table.Field}, 2))
      )
```

This is really the question:

Is there a 3rd (and better) option after 1) showing a bad date incorrectly or 2) report choking if a free-form string date is formatted differently?

Comment: You've got like three questions there, so it's kind of hard to answer. Also, what exactly are "really old dates"? You're basically just trying to gracefully handle a date stored in a string, correct?

Comment: If your dates are manually entered as strings and in different possible formats then you don't have much of a choice but to check each possibility. The `DateValue` function is a good start, but obviously it won't be able to handle every possible input. FYI, `DateValue` also can't handle years below 100 which is why your first date said 1931.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't 'correct' the date--it's a slippery slope that leads to correcting all sorts of user- or system-generated errors.

It's better to note the issue and discuss it with the proper individuals.  That way the process error and data can be corrected.

Comment: @craig - yes, but I only found this issue when testing, and if a bad date prints as something kind of valid, it may be pretty hard to spot.  It certainly isn't obvious that the date displayed is completely different from the database.

Comment: @Ryan - I was trying to find out how far back DateValue would work.  Thank you.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - you are right.  I tried to clarify that some, since the last part is what I really care about: is there an option besides invisible wrong data or the report potentially choking?

Comment: Ultimately the issue is that data is allowed to be entered like this in the first place. This is a front-end issue. If users can enter the data as dirty as they want, you won't be able to clean it 100% of the time. I think the best "3rd option" would be to do a simple check to see if the data is in acceptable bounds and just throw it away if it fails.

Comment: @Ryan - I agree with all except the last statement.  If it fails, it needs to be visible, so the user can fix it.  My third option, right now, is based on information I didn't provide: I'm fixing the underlying Oracle query to convert it to a date.  I'll still need to catch the cases where the formatting is really off.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two formulas: one that's a date and on that is a string.  Show the date version for 'new' dates and the string one for 'old' dates.  The string one would concatenate the values as desired.

```
// {@date_version}
DateValue ({Table.Field})
```

Suppression logic: `CurrentFieldValue<Date(1980,1,1)`

```
// {@stirng_version}
{Table.Field}[6 to 7] + "/" + {Table.Field}[9 to 10] + "/19??"
```

Suppression logic: `{@date_version}>Date(1980,1,1)`